# What's the best MySQL alternative to dual?

Tags: mysql

So, primarily I work in oracle and have gotten spoiled by working with dual. For a user with select privileges on a given database how could you reproduce the dual functionality?

IE:

```
Select 'foo' from dual
```

Probably a very simple answer that I'm just missing.

Comment: Thanks guys - didn't realize DUAL was available in MySQL :)

Comment: See @SeparateReality’s answer below for an important point: you’ll need `FROM dual` if you want to include a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I remember using `Select 1 from dual` in oracle and just `select 1;` in mysql. So I think you just try without a table reference.

This was to verify connectivity so not sure if it applies in your case.

Answer (score 11):

You are permitted to specify DUAL as a dummy table name in situations where no tables are [referenced](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html):

```
SELECT 1+1;
```

OR

```
SELECT 1 + 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score 9):

In most cases you can just omit `FROM DUAL` in MySQL and MariaDB.

But [if you need a `WHERE`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/dual/) to verify things, you still need the `FROM DUAL`.

Example (usage: one way to avoid re-inserting with different id):

```
INSERT INTO `t1`(`id`, `name`, `description`) 
    SELECT NULL, 'LopsusNonsus', 'my description'
        FROM DUAL 
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM `t1` WHERE `name`='LopsusNonsus' LIMIT 1) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `information_schema.schemata` table for the current session database as it has one row for each database.

```
select
1
from
information_schema.schemata
where
schema_name = database()
```

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you don’t need `FROM dual`. This is in common with most other DBMSs.

MySQL and MariaDB both let you use `FROM dual` if you like, but that’s only really useful for copying & pasting code between them.

If you really want to use `FROM dual` with the others, you can use something like this:

```sql
--  PostgreSQL, MSSQL, SQLite
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dual;
    CREATE TABLE dual(
        dummy CHAR(1)
    );
    INSERT INTO dual VALUES('X');
```

That replicates Oracle’s `dual` table.